# Overlapping bar plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to hide a variable in a stacked bar chart in a dataset.
Below is the dataset:

Comment: Hi @Sam, could you please share your data using `dput(popByAgeEthnicity)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: I have added popByAgeEthnicity dataset. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First convert `Ethnic.group` to a factor, then filter the data frame to only contain the entries where `Ethnic.group != "Asian"`. This will mean that `Ethnic.group` "remembers" that there is a category called "Asian", even though it contains no actual "Asian" values.

To use this "memory" in your plot, add `+ scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)` to include all factor levels even when some of the levels are not represented in the data.

These two steps will keep "Asian" in the legend as a possible value, but without any actual entries on the plot, and maintain the colours that were present in your original plot.

```r
popByAgeEthnicity %>%
  mutate(Ethnic.group = factor(Ethnic.group)) %>%
  filter(Ethnic.group != "Asian") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Age.group, Pop, fill = Ethnic.group)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

As a side note, writing `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` is just a long way of writing `geom_col()`

Comment: Hi Sam. I am only plotting the data you have provided. What is it you want to show? You would have to make all your `pop` values smaller to match the lower plot, but this seems like a random and unjustified thing to do. Can you explain what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: I see. I'll have a look Sam. Your question title says that this is a stacked bar chart and you were trying to hide a group. What you are describing isn't a stacked bar chart at all. Are you sure you want it that way rather than a dodged bar chart, where the values start from 0, but you can see all the values? Almost everyone looking at a plot like the one you describe will assume it is stacked, and will not interpret it properly.